# CSS grid layout is on parent div, I want to use it on a child div as well

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js, css-grid

In this project I'm combining fullPage with CSS Grid Layout.

I currently have a grid defined on the first div called "section", but also want the contents of the "slide" div to conform to this same grid.

Below is the hierarchy.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="fp slides">
        <div class="slides container">
            <div class="slide>
```

For clarification I also made [a pen](https://codepen.io/sneakyvince/pen/wPrbyB) where the problem is isolated.

Currently the CSS grid auto placement just [puts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA5lI.png) "fp slides" in the first table cell (row 1, column 1) along with all the content it's children has (an h1, h2, p and h3). It should use all available rows/columns.

I've tried setting the grid-area of "fp slides" to all 6 cells but that doesn't preserve the rows and columns and just puts all content in "slide" underneath each other.

Is there a CSS Grid Layout option to make this work?

Comment: Sounds like you're after `display:sub-grid` but unfortunately that's not supported by any browser at the moment.

Comment: Sub grid is for when you want a grid within another grid. I just want my grid to carry over to child div's.

Comment: Fair enough...fact is then I suspect...you can't. That's not the way grid works. Perhaps a proper *reduced case* demo rather than link to the site.

Comment: I made a pen with the reduced case here: https://codepen.io/sneakyvince/pen/wPrbyB

Comment: Something like this perhaps? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOOREZ

Comment: No, unfortunately this still doesnt put the h1, h2 and h3 in their correct cells but instead it just places them underneath eachother. If you have trouble understanding my problem try opening this pen in Firefox and display the grid in the inspector.

Answer (score 6):

You could mark the children that shouldn't be included in the grid as `display: contents`. This more or less takes them out of the DOM, so that their children are seen as grid-items. But beware that this removes other styling, like background, as well. You may only style the grid-items.

Unfortunately this is not yet supported in Edge. But you can vote for the feature [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/10938981-implement-the-box-generation-keywords-from-css-dis).

I've updated the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKgabG) with:

```
.fp-slides, .fp-slidesContainer, .slide {
  display: contents;
}
```